# Effect vs Affect

Tags: word-usage

Please see the following sentence written in the context of requesting renaming of a current email id:

"*However, with only the name change **affected**, sending mail to the erstwhile email id  was permanently disabled*."

I am confused as to whether affected should be the right word to use here or effected?
Any explanation of the right word to use will be very helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: "Affect" is a verb,  "Effect" is a noun  (except in rare situations that need not worry about) Please consult a dictionary, which will explain further.  If you have already consulted a dictionary, please explain what more is unclear.

Comment: In your sentence you are using a verb, in past participle form.

Comment: @JamesK - I'm not sure about that. Effect can be a verb - 'the government effected changes' [I'm a sound engineer, so effect kind of comes up a lot in conversation] To me, the quote should be 'effected'.

Comment: See my little bracket "except in rare situations"  Using effect correctly as a word "THe government effected change" is one of the rarities.  If you need to ask about the difference, then the rare cases where effect is a verb (and affect is a noun) are not yet part of your English study.   But if you want to find out about effect as a verb, the  dictionary will tell you about that too.@DoneWithThis.

Comment: @JamesK - I don't know how 'rare' you think it may be, but to me we have one of those right here. Paraphrase, "With only the name changed, but not the password, mail fails." > "With only the name change effected, the mail fails." Sending mail is affected by the change effected.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's talking about the result of an action, a noun is appropriate in this context and hence "*effect*" is the most suitable word here.

> *However, with only the name change **effected**, sending mail to the
> erstwhile email id was permanently disabled.*

Comment: One effects change by doing A, B or C. But a name change cannot be "effected" in most cases.

Comment: Email was renamed from A@example.com to B@example.com. Hence, the name change was 'effected'?

Comment: No, the change **was made**. effect is too heavy a word here.